# Did Bhima drink the blood of Duhsasana in the Mahabharata war?

Tags: mahabharata, bhima

It is said that Bhima drank the blood of Duhsasana in the Mahabharata war.

Please post the relevant verses from the Mahabharata about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, he did. From Bibek Debroy's [translation](https://www.amazon.in/dp/B06XYPG9XX) based on the Critical Edition of the Mahābhārata:

> #### Karna-Vadha Parva
>
> #### Chapter 1211 (61)
>
> Sanjaya said, "Prince Duhshasana accomplished an extremely difficult
>   task in that tumultuous battle. He severed Bhima's bow with a
>   razor-sharp arrow and pierced his charioteer with six arrows. In an
>   instant, the great-souled one then struck Bhimasena with many
>   excellent arrows. Bhimasena hurled a fierce club towards him. It
>   struck Duhshasana and flung him a distance of ten bow-lengths away,
>   rendering him like a wounded elephant with shattered temples. He was
>   struck and fell down, trembling. O Indra among kings! It slew his
>   horses and charioteer and having crushed the horses and the chariot,
>   fell down. His armour, ornaments and garments were destroyed and,
>   completely immobile, he shrieked in pain. The spirited Bhimasena
>   remembered all the acts of enmity that had been performed by your
>   sons. He jumped down from the chariot onto the ground and eagerly
>   looked at him. He grasped an extremely sharp sword and placed it
>   against the throat of the trembling one. **He tore apart the breast of
>   the one who had fallen down on the ground and drank the warm blood.** He
>   repeatedly savoured the taste.
>
> Then, excessively angry, he glanced at him and spoke these words.
>   'This is superior to mother's milk, honey, clarified butter,
>   well-prepared liquor, celestial water and skimmed and churned milk. It
>   is my view today, that the blood of my enemies is tastier than all of
>   these.' He again repeated these cheerful and eloquent words.
>
> Whoever saw Bhimasena in that state then, fell down in distress and in
>   fear. men the men fell down there, the weapons also fell down from
>   their hands. Others were terrified and glanced at him with half-open
>   eyes, uttering loud lamentations of woe. All those who saw Bhima drink
>   Duhshasana's blood were terrified and miserable and ran away in
>   different directions. They said, 'This one is not human.'
>
> In the hearing of the brave ones in the world, he spoke these words.
>   'O worst of men! I am drinking the blood from your throat. In great
>   rage, you repeatedly called us cattle. When I was asleep in
>   Pramanakoti, you fed me poison and made me suffer the hardship of
>   being bitten by serpents. You burnt us down in the house of lac. You
>   robbed our kingdom through a gambling match and made us dwell in the
>   woods. We were robbed of the happiness in our homes and suffered from
>   weapons in battle. There were many other hardships and we have never
>   known any joy. Dhritarashtra and his son have always acted maliciously
>   towards us.' O king! O great king! Having spoken these words,
>   Vrikodara, who had obtained victory, again spoke these words to
>   Keshava and Arjuna. 'O brave ones! **I had taken a vow about Duhshasana
>   in the battle. I have accomplished that today.** I will accomplish the
>   second vow now too, that of killing Duryodhana like a sacrificial
>   animal. In the presence of the Kouravas, I will press down the
>   evil-souled one's head with my foot and obtain peace.'
>
> Having spoken these words, he cheerfully roared, blood streaming from
>   his body. The extremely powerful and great-souled one danced, like the
>   one with one thousand eyes after Vritra's death."

Here are the [Sanskrit verses](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs08061.htm) for the same chapter:

> Book 8
>
> Chapter 61
>
> 1. [s] 
>      tatrākarod duṣkaraṃ rājaputro; duḥśāsanas tumule yudhyamānaḥ 
>      ciccheda bhīmasya dhanuḥ kṣureṇa; ṣaḍbhiḥ śaraiḥ sārathim apy avidhyat
> 2. tato 'bhinad bahubhiḥ kṣipram eva; vareṣubhir bhīmasenaṃ mahātmā 
>      sa vikṣaran nāga iva prabhinno; gadām asmai tumule prāhiṇod vai
> 3. tayāharad daśa dhanvantarāṇi; duḥśāsanaṃ bhīmasenaḥ prasahya 
>      tayā hataḥ patito vepamāno; duḥśāsano gadayā vegavatyā
> 4. hayāḥ sasūtāś ca hatā narendra; cūrṇīkṛtaś cāsya rataḥ patantyā 
>      vidhvastavarmābharaṇāmbara srag; viceṣṭamāno bhṛśavedanārtaḥ
> 5. tataḥ smṛtvā bhīmasenas tarasvī; sāpatnakaṃ yat prayuktaṃ sutais te 
>      rathād avaplutya gataḥ sa bhūmau; yatnena tasmin praṇidhāya cakṣuḥ
> 6. asiṃ samuddhṛtya śitaṃ sudhāraṃ; kaṇṭhe samākramya ca vepamānam 
>      **utkṛtya vakṣaḥ patitasya bhūmāv**; **athāpibac choṇitam asya koṣṇam** 
>      āsvādya cāsvādya ca vīkṣamāṇaḥ; kruddho 'tivelaṃ prajagāda vākyam
> 7. stanyasya mātur madhusarpiṣo vā; mādhvīka pānasya ca satkṛtasya 
>      divyasya vā toyarasasya pānāt; payo dadhibhyāṃ mathitāc ca mukhyāt 
>      sarvebhya evābhyadhiko raso 'yaṃ; mato mamādyāhita lohitasya
> 8. evaṃ bruvāṇaṃ punar ādravantam; āsvādya valgantam atiprahṛṣṭam 
>      ye bhīmasenaṃ dadṛśus tadānīṃ; bhayena te 'pi vyathitā nipetuḥ
> 9. ye cāpi tatrāpatitā manuṣyās; teṣāṃ karebhyaḥ patitaṃ ca śastram 
>      bhayāc ca saṃcukruśur uccakais te; nimīlitākṣā dadṛśuś ca tan na
> 10. ye tatra bhīmaṃ dadṛśuḥ samantād; dauḥśāsanaṃ tadrudhiraṃ pibantam 
>       sarve palāyanta bhayābhipannā; nāyaṃ manuṣya iti bhāṣamāṇāḥ
> 11. śṛṇvatāṃ lokavīrāṇām idaṃ vacanam abravīt 
>       eṣa te rudhiraṃ kaṇṭhāt pibāmi puruṣādhama 
>       brūhīdānīṃ susaṃrabdhaḥ punar gaur iti gaur iti
> 12. pramāṇa koṭyāṃ śayanaṃ kālakūṭasya bhojanam 
>       daśanaṃ cāhibhiḥ kaṣṭaṃ dāhaṃ ca jatu veśmani
> 13. dyūtena rājyaharaṇam araṇye vasatiś ca yā 
>       iṣvastrāṇi ca saṃgrāmeṣv asukhāni ca veśmani
> 14. duḥkhāny etāni jānīmo na sukhāni kadā cana 
>       dhṛtarāṣṭrasya daurātmyāt saputrasyā sadā vayam
> 15. ity uktvā vacanaṃ rājañ jayaṃ prāpya vṛkodaraḥ 
>       punar āha mahārāja smayaṃs tau keśavārjunau
> 16. **duḥśāsane yad raṇe saṃśrutaṃ me; tad vai sarvaṃ kṛtam adyeha vīrau** 
>       adyaiva dāsyāmy aparaṃ dvitīyaṃ; duryodhanaṃ yajñapaśuṃ viśasyā 
>       śiromṛditvā ca padā durātmanaḥ; śāntiṃ lapsye kauravāṇāṃ samakṣam
> 17. etāvad uktvā vacanaṃ prahṛṣṭo; nanād acoccai rudhirārdragātraḥ 
>       nanarta caivātibalo mahātmā; vṛtraṃ nihatyeva sahasranetraḥ